# Python script hangs when getting queue entries after running Process

Tags: python-3.x, queue, multiprocess

I'm trying to learn the multiprocessing module in Python 3.  My toy problem is an Euler integration of particle trajectories in a Lennard-Jones potential, which I've added in the code-block below.

When `mpSwich` is `False`, the function `Integrate` is run in the current process and the code executes as you would expect.  Otherwise `Integrate` is run in a child process and the script hangs.  When I step through this with the debugger it looks like the hang occurs when I try to get the trajectory out of the child process with `results.update(outputQueue.get())`.  I'm not entirely convinced that this is the cause rather than a symptom of the hang, either way I'm struggling to get the root of the problem.  I plan to run a child process for one time step value `Dt` then, in parallel, for several values of `Dt`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import multiprocessing as mp

# calculate position and momentum
def Integrate(Dt, output):
    T = np.float64(100.0)
    N = np.int(T/Dt)
    q = np.zeros((N, 3))
    p = np.zeros((N, 3))
    q[0, :] = 1.9
    p[0, :] = -0.0001
    LJ = lambda x: x**-12 - 2.0*x**-6
    M = np.float64(45.0)

    # Euler method
    for nn in range(N - 1):
        q[nn + 1, :] = q[nn, :] + Dt*p[nn, :]        
        h = np.abs(q[nn + 1, :] - q[nn, :]) * np.ones(3)
        dphidq = (LJ(q[nn, :] + h) - LJ(q[nn, :] - h))/(2.0*h)    
        p[nn + 1, :] = p[nn, :] - Dt*dphidq/M

    # store results in queue
    outdict = {}
    outdict[Dt] = [q, p]
    output.put(outdict)

# manage simulation
mpSwitch = True
if mpSwitch:
    # launch process to perform simulation
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        outputQueue = mp.Queue()
        p = mp.Process(target = Integrate, args = (np.float64(0.001), outputQueue))
        p.start()

        results = {}
        results.update(outputQueue.get())

        p.join()
else:
    # perform simulation in current process
    outputQueue = mp.Queue()
    Integrate(np.float64(0.001), outputQueue)
    results = {}
    results.update(outputQueue.get())

#plot results
plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
plt.title('Phase Diagram')
plt.plot(results[0.001][0][:, 0], results[0.001][1][:, 0], '.-')
plt.xlabel('Coordinate')
plt.ylabel('Momentum')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a a silly mistake on my part.  It's a scoping issue, if the plotting section is moved under the `if __name__ == '__main__'` statement then this code seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with ThreadPoolExecutor from concurrent.futures package and see if the behavior can be reproduced for the same example?

Comment: I was hoping to use something a little simpler for this as I'm still learning how to use the multiprocessing module.  There seem to be plenty of similar examples about that I've tried but that don't seem to work applied to this problem.